# Cordova not running normally

Tags: javascript, cordova, phonegap-build

The problem is:

I have index.html with this code:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="../platforms/android/assets/www/cordova.js">
```

When I run this file in a browser, there is alert:

> gap_init:2

Click "Ok" and I have second alert:

> [true] gap:[null,"App","overrideBackbutton","App1966010284"]

In my console output I have:
Endless loop

> processMessag failed: invalid message: " "

**Question: How I can fix this?**

*Linux Ubuntu 14.04, 
cordova v. 4.2.0,
phonegap v. 3.6.3-0.22.0*

Thank you!

Comment: change `<script type="text/javascript" src="../platforms/android/assets/www/cordova.js">` to `<script type="text/javascript" src="cordova.js">` ad deploy to an emulator or device

Comment: I also have faced some "endless loop" generating >100k such messages in the console. I started tracking down: the console message is written in cordova.js line 1056, JS function 'processMessage()'. The comment there above refers to class 'org.apache.cordova.NativeToJsMessageQueue'. (Messages from native part to the webview are sent by adding some tags to the end of the web content, e.g. in order to fire the 'deviceready' event.) There in Java, it goes 'popAndEncode()' -> 'packMessage()' -> 'encodeAsMessage()'. But now just before debugging, the messages don't appear anymore. It is a phantom.