# Application infinite loop with processMessage failed error

Tags: javascript, cordova

My Cordova app not running in browser and mobile it shows an error

> processMessage failed

**Screenshot:**

[image]

and goes infinite loop and it freezes the device any solution?

This question is already in asked here [Cordova not running normally](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28256021/cordova-not-running-normally) but there is not an answer so thats why I have to asked it again.

Answer (score 15):

Getting the same issue (using Chrome with the phonegap desktop emulator. What I see as happening is this.

There seems to be a bug in Cordova.js that fails to check for an empty message.
When the app sends out alerts:
gap_init:2
gap:[0,"StatusBar","_ready","StatusBar1593157203"]
gap:[0,"App","show","App1593157204"]
gap:[0,"File","requestAllPaths","File1593157205"]
gap:[0,"NetworkStatus","getConnectionInfo","NetworkStatus1593157206"]
gap:[0,"Device","getDeviceInfo","Device1593157207"]

and you just hit 'OK', instead of clearing out the contents of that dialog box it going on to cause an infinite loooooop. I don't know the significance of these messages yes as I'm pretty new to Cordova, but it's hell and gone from the principle of least surprise!

So you can  clear out the messages, or modify the cordova.js code where it gets stuck in the loop. You also could turn off the alerts that also works.

the function processMessage() (see below) doesn't test for an empty string, which in and of itself might be fine, but it is called from a while loop which only checks for "*" if its going to pop.

```
while (messagesFromNative.length) {
            var msg = popMessageFromQueue();
            // The Java side can send a * message to indicate that it
            // still has messages waiting to be retrieved.
            if (msg == '*' && messagesFromNative.length === 0) {
                setTimeout(pollOnce, 0);
                return;
            }
            processMessage(msg);
        }

// Processes a single message, as encoded by NativeToJsMessageQueue.java.
    function processMessage(message) {
        try {
            var firstChar = message.charAt(0);
            if (firstChar == 'J') {
                eval(message.slice(1));
            } else if (firstChar == 'S' || firstChar == 'F') {
                var success = firstChar == 'S';
                var keepCallback = message.charAt(1) == '1';
                var spaceIdx = message.indexOf(' ', 2);
                var status = +message.slice(2, spaceIdx);
                var nextSpaceIdx = message.indexOf(' ', spaceIdx + 1);
                var callbackId = message.slice(spaceIdx + 1, nextSpaceIdx);
                var payloadKind = message.charAt(nextSpaceIdx + 1);
                var payload;
                if (payloadKind == 's') {
                    payload = message.slice(nextSpaceIdx + 2);
                } else if (payloadKind == 't') {
                    payload = true;
                } else if (payloadKind == 'f') {
                    payload = false;
                } else if (payloadKind == 'N') {
                    payload = null;
                } else if (payloadKind == 'n') {
                    payload = +message.slice(nextSpaceIdx + 2);
                } else if (payloadKind == 'A') {
                    var data = message.slice(nextSpaceIdx + 2);
                    var bytes = window.atob(data);
                    var arraybuffer = new Uint8Array(bytes.length);
                    for (var i = 0; i < bytes.length; i++) {
                        arraybuffer[i] = bytes.charCodeAt(i);
                    }
                    payload = arraybuffer.buffer;
                } else if (payloadKind == 'S') {
                    payload = window.atob(message.slice(nextSpaceIdx + 2));
                } else {
                    payload = JSON.parse(message.slice(nextSpaceIdx + 1));
                }
                cordova.callbackFromNative(callbackId, success, status, [payload], keepCallback);
            } else {
                console.log("processMessage failed: invalid message: " + JSON.stringify(message));
            }
        } catch (e) {
            console.log("processMessage failed: Error: " + e);
            console.log("processMessage failed: Stack: " + e.stack);
            console.log("processMessage failed: Message: " + message);
        }
    }
```

Comment: How do you turn off the alerts?

Comment: just replace `= +prompt('','..')` with `= ''; //+prompt('','..')`
P.S. use `subl .` to open the directory  in sublime and then use `Ctrl+Shift+F` to find and replace all the prompts.

Answer (score 0):

Check your cordova js loading properly? is the path for cordova js is proper?

give path like this in your index.html:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="cordova.js">
```

Comment: i already add the cordova.js file in  index.html but when i remove it the work fine in browser

Comment: Then check while making app do you have cordova.js file in your www folder?

Comment: You can host your app in tomat server then you don'y have to remove cordova js referennce from your html file.

Comment: i think tomcat is server and its for java right tomat is not server

Comment: you just copy your app inside webapps folder of tomcat and run using localhost:portnumber/ProjectFolderName

Comment: If cordova was not loading, he wouldn't get the error message in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

I had the problem in an Angular 6 project. It was simply solved by deleting **cordova.js** which was under **src** folder.

Answer (score 0):

I was not able to resolve this issue when viewing the `/android` platform option for `cordova serve`; however, the `/ios` platform option did function properly.

Not much of a solution, but perhaps a mildly helpful workaround for those who follow.